# Replace String in Bash with Specific Condition

Tags: string, bash, replace

If I have string:

`path1=/path/me & you/file.json&path2=/path/you & me/file.txt`

I expect the output to be like this:

`path1=/path/me & you/file.json;path2=/path/you & me/file.txt`

I need to replace `&` that it's front and back not contain `space`, I tried with `sed` but I keep got this

`path1=/path/me ; you/file.json;path2=/path/you ; me/file.txt`

Comment: Are you actually trying to parse URL query parameters?

Comment: Your question should really include the `sed` script you tried, and perhaps explain your thinking behind it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `[^ ]` to match a non-space character and make sure it's in a `\(capture group\)` so that you can reference it in the replacement string:

```
sed -e 's/\([^ ]\)&\([^ ]\)/\1;\2/'
```

This finds any three character sequence of  `non-space` `&` `non-space` and replaces it just the two captured characters, effectively replacing any `&` without a space next to it.

This will affect `foo&bar` but not `foo & bar` or `foo& bar` or `&foo`

Comment: The OP's expectation would be: `sed -e 's/\([^ ]\)&\([^ ]\)/\1;\2/'`. You may have overlooked the semicolon in between.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -r 's/(\S)&(\S)/\1;\2/g'
```

Where -r enable regex and \S is all except spaces.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing maybe you are looking for

```
sed 's/&\([a-z][a-z0-9]*=\)/;\1/g'
```

i.e. replace only semicolons which are immediately followed by a token and an equals sign. (You may have to adjust the token definition, depending on what your tokens can look like. For example, underscore is often supported, but rarely used. You mght want to support uppercase, too.)

If at all possible, fix the process which produces these values, as the format is inherently ambiguous.